# XML how do i add an attribute?

Tags: android, xml

I have a button called "about" SO the name would be About and the value would equal Button right? Came up with this code for string.xml   About  and then for main.xml i have   android:clickable="@string/Buy"> What am i doing wrong because im still getting the error :  "[I18N] Hardcoded string "About", should use @string resource
Issue: Looks for hardcoded text attributes which should be converted to resource lookup
Hardcoding text attributes directly in layout files is bad for several reasons:" Thanks for the Help! :}

Comment: can you post your layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

android:clickable should be true or false only

and android:text="@string/About"